# Split dataset into yearly time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that gives me a unique identifier and different columns with values for each year. It looks as follows:

| ID | value90 | value91 | value92 | value93 | .. | value16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | .. | 5 |
| EFGH | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | .. | 10 |
| IJKL | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | .. | 15 |

```
df = pd.Dataframe({'ID':[ABCD, EFGH, IJKL], 'value90':[1, 6, 11], 'value91':[2,7,12], 'value92':[3,8,13], 'value93':[4,9,14], 'value16':[5,10,15]}
```

I am looking for the following output:

| Year | ID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | ABC | 1 |
| 1991 | ABC | 2 |
| 1992 | ABC | 3 |
| ... | ..... | ... |
| 2016 | ABC | 5 |
| ... | ..... | ... |
| 2016 | IJKL | 15 |

I'm using pandas and am not sure how to produce the final output I'm seeking. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to get most of the way there, and then sort:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL'], 'value90':[1, 6, 11], 'value91':[2,7,12], 'value92':[3,8,13], 'value93':[4,9,14], 'value16':[5,10,15]})

print(df)

df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["ID"],var_name="Year", value_name="Value")
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['ID'])
df2 = df2.filter(["Year","ID","Value"])

print(df2)
```

[**Output**]

```
     ID  value90  value91  value92  value93  value16
0  ABCD        1        2        3        4        5
1  EFGH        6        7        8        9       10
2  IJKL       11       12       13       14       15



       Year    ID  Value
0   value90  ABCD      1
3   value91  ABCD      2
6   value92  ABCD      3
9   value93  ABCD      4
12  value16  ABCD      5
1   value90  EFGH      6
4   value91  EFGH      7
7   value92  EFGH      8
10  value93  EFGH      9
13  value16  EFGH     10
2   value90  IJKL     11
5   value91  IJKL     12
8   value92  IJKL     13
11  value93  IJKL     14
14  value16  IJKL     15
```